# Incremental Measure of Independence between $2$ random variables

Tags: probability

I have $2$ random variables $X$ and $Y$ each producing a sequence of values $\{x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_0, y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n\}$

Is there an incremental(not batch) way of measuring the independence between the variables $X$ and $Y$ ?

For my problems I get to see output of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ one by one and I need to calculate a measure of the independence between $X$ and $Y$ on an incremental basis.

thanks,
Sarvi

Comment: I changed $x_3$ to $x_2$. I assumed it was a typo. Please correct me if that is what you had intended to put originally.

Comment: you are correct. thanks